# Using variables with fasterq-dump?

Tags: bash, sratoolkit, fastq-dump

I am trying to download multiple fastq files from the SRA NCBI database which, conveniently enough, have their IDs in a range. Building a simple loop doesn't seem to do the trick, as bash appears to interpret my variable as an additional command? Help would be appreciated. This is what I have for now:

````
for i in {256..345};do
    sra_code = "DRR163""$i"
fasterq-dump "$sra_code" -p -v --outdir ./output/ -e 8 

done
```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an obvious error in your shell script that should have given you an error message:

```
sra_code = "DRR163""$i"
```

Should be:

```
sra_code="DRR163""$i"
```

You cannot have spaces around the `=` sign in a variable assignment. The line `sra_code = "DRR163""$i"` means "run the command `sra_code` with the arguments `= "DRR163""$i"`. Since there is no such command, you see an error.

Here's a working version of your command:

```
for i in {256..345}; do 
    sra_code="DRR163$i"
    fasterq-dump "$sra_code" -p -v --outdir ./output/ -e 8
done
```

Answer (score 0):

> which, conveniently enough, have their IDs in a range

I think it's a bit risky to rely on that - for this particular case they are not going to change but you may need to download more samples in the future.

I would suggest avoiding `sra` and `fastq(er)-dump` altogether and use [ena](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browser/home) instead.

In your case, it seems you want the runs in project PRJDB7736. From here https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/browser/view/PRJDB7736 you can get a tabular file (see link in *Download report ... TSV*) with the sample characteristics. Column `fastq_ftp` gives you the ftp link to the fastq files that you can pass to `wget` or `curl`.

You can also get the same report programmatically with:

```
curl -s -X GET "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/portal/api/filereport?accession=PRJDB7736&fields=run_accession,sample_description,library_name,library_layout,fastq_ftp&result=read_run" > ena.tsv
```

You should edit the `fields=...` list to suite your needs. The fields available are those from:

```
curl -X GET "https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena/portal/api/returnFields?dataPortal=ena&result=read_run"
```

I don't know what you think... I find this route much more useful and transparent than sra's.